# django update model while dropping extra kwargs

Tags: django, models

I have a `Row` class and a `SpottedPub` model. They are almost the same except that `Row` has a couple extra fields.

What i need to do is to gracefully update `spottedpub` fields from `row` object attributes. I tried this

```
spotted_pubs = SpottedPub.objects.filter(notification__rule__suite__campaign=self,
                                         name=particular_row.name)
if spotted_pubs.all():
    spotted_pubs.update(**row.__dict__)
```

but I get an error saying that I pass too many kwargs to `update()`:

```
FieldDoesNotExist: SpottedPub has no field named 'profit_weight'
```

is there a way to drop kwargs that don't correspond to fields?

I tried writing a custom manager

```
class CustomSpottedPubManager(models.Manager):

    def update_drop_fields(self, **fields):
        queryset = super(CustomSpottedPubManager, self).get_queryset()
        print(queryset)
        # drop unwanted fields here
        queryset.update(**fields)
```

and attaching it to the model

```
class SpottedPub(BaseUserObject):
    objects = CustomSpottedPubManager()
```

but `update_drop_fields()` method doesn't get called because I access this method already after filtering:

```
filter(notification__rule__suite__campaign=self,
                                         name=particular_row.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to create an `update_drop_fields` and filter the fields looks good.

You can create a queryset with the custom `update_drop_fields()` method,

```
class CustomSpottedPubQueryset(models.QuerySet):

    def update_drop_fields(self, **fields):
        return self.update(**fields)
```

then [create a manager with the queryset methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#create-manager-with-queryset-methods).

```
class SpottedPub(BaseUserObject):
    objects = CustomSpottedPubQueryset.as_manager()
```